# Count owned entries per yearWeek

Tags: mysql, sql

With this query I get all my owned entries

```
select
  SUM(quantity) AS sumQuantity
from
  data
```

Now I would like to know how much I have owned in each week. I have tried, but of course I only get how much I have added/removed each week. Can I somehow read this out with SQL, or do I need some php?

```
select
  SUM(quantity) AS sumQuantity,
  CONCAT(
    YEAR(entry_date),
    WEEK(entry_date)
  ) AS yearWeek
from
  data
group by
  yearWeek
order by
  yearWeek desc
```

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055) PS. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You current query gives you the total quantity per week of each year. I suspect that you are after a running sum ; in MySQL 8.0, we can this with `sum() over()` like so:

```
select
    sum(quantity) AS sumQuantity,
    sum(sum(quantity)) over(order by yearweek(entry_date)) AS runningQuantity
    yearweek(entry_date) AS yearWeek
from data
group by yearWeek
order by yearWeek desc
```

Side note: you can use [built-in fucntion `yearweek()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek) for the year/week computation.

Comment: I replace year_week with YEARWEEK() and this work great. Thank you very much